# How to convert std::queue<float> to float[]?

Tags: c++, arrays, queue

I know I could iteratively pop the elements into an array, but would prefer to directly cast it if possible.

Comment: A `queue` is not an array, so you don't.

Comment: The default underlying container for std::queue is [`std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) which is not a contiguous container.  So even if you could access it the data is not in 1 contiguous block.  Simplest is going to be `std::vector<float> my_vec{ my_q.begin(), my_q.end() };`, and then use `my_vec::data()` which returns a pointer to the underlying array

Comment: @RichardCritten Note unlike a container, a `queue` adaptor does not expose the begin and end iterator, so you would have to read and pop each element manually.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to "cast" a `std::queue` or `std::deque` to a vector or an array.

You can however copy the content of a double ended queue into another container:

```
deque<int> d{1,2,3,4}; 
vector<int> v(d.size());

copy(d.cbegin(),d.cend(), v.begin());

for (auto i:v) cout<< i<<endl;
```

The same for a built-in array,  provided you have allocated one of sufficient size:

```
int a[4];  // or dynamic allocation, but vector is more convenient then. 
copy(d.cbegin(),d.cend(), a);
```

Comment: Note the question has specifically asked for `queue`, not `deque`.

Comment: The question is not very clear about the intent, referred to a queue, but didn't tell that other forms of queue cannot be used.  So my answer is to be understood as :cast is not possible,  but if a dequeue can be used, there's another solution. I didn't repeat the iterative pop, since OP already knows the solution.

Comment: I have a collection of float that are currently held together within this datatype: std::queue<float>. I want those same numbers now in this data type: float[]. My question is the best way to do that. In the question I reference that I don't know if casting is possible (and many people have replied indicating it is not).

Comment: @JamesArnold I maintain that it is not possible to cast. Moreover, in the case of the queue in general, you cannot access its content without changing the queue. So it’s not possible to create an adapter that could leave the queue unchanged. You could do this only if you’d make assumptions about the queue (i.e. it would not work on every queue, just on queues with specific containers). In this case casting is still not possible (unless you’d use a vector as underlying container), and copy to an array is the only way to meet the requirent.

Comment: @JamesArnold But the question is: why donyou need to use a queue in first place? Why not opt for a more flexible queue? (in which case you could copy its content to an array using constant non destructive iterators)

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer, you can't cast a `queue` to an array. Even if you expose the underlying container, it would likely be a `deque` or `list`, which cannot be cast to an array since the data are not stored contiguously.

---

The straightforward way is to just read/pop each element, and push them to another `vector`.

---

However, you can also inherit from a `queue` and expose the underlying container:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class exposed_queue : public std::queue<T>
{
public:
    using std::queue<T>::c;
};
```

Now you are able to access the underlying container, and have a easy way to fill a `vector`:

```cpp
std::queue<float> q {{1,2,3,4,5}};
exposed_queue<float> eq(q);

std::vector<float> v(eq.c.begin(), eq.c.end());
```

Comment: Interesting idea.  However from a design perspective, your alternative solution tries to expose something that was meant to be hidden, which is not in the spirit of sound encapsulation.  Moreover, having access to the underlying container does not solve the problem:  if the queue could be any queue,  the only guarantees about the underlying container are back(),front(),push_back(),pop_front().  If OP can chose the underlying container, he could chose q deque and use my solution.

Comment: Now, if you complete your solution with some template magic to either construct a vector when it's possible, or iterate through underlying container, I'll upvote ;-)

Comment: @Christophe You are right, a `queue` only requires the underlying container to have `back()`, `front()`, `push_back()`, `pop_front()`. However, the question has specifically asked for `std::queue<float>`, which means the underlying container is defaulted to `std::deque`.

Comment: @Christophe Also, despite the underlying container is an `std::deque`, you cannot access the `begin` and `end` iterator directly without accessing the underlying container, hence my answer about exposing the underlying container.